# Spherical Gaussian Sigma dimension

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, maximum-likelihood

I think I am confused with this thing.

If we have a 3 dimension Gaussian then the MLE estimate for $\mu$ is a vector with 3 element

$$\mu(1)' = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j = 1} ^ n x_j\text{   and so on }\mu(2)\text{ for }y\text{  and  }\mu(3)\text{ for }z$$

also $\sigma$

$$    \sigma(1)' =  \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j = 1} ^ n(x_j - \mu')}\text{ and so on }\sigma(2)\text{ for }y\text{ and }\sigma(3)\text{ for }z$$

When we know that the $x,y,z$ are not independent, in which case the covarience matrix looks like this:  $\sigma\cdot I$ where $\sigma$ is a number and $I$ an $3\times 3$ identity matrix?

How can we compute $\sigma$?

Thanks for the answers an

Comment: You seem to ignoring the covariances between the components.

Comment: yeah, this is what I can't understand, and why $\sigma%$ is a number, why not 3 length vector? thanks for your comment

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution

Comment: thanks, but here I can't see covariance like this $\I * \sigma$ where $\sigma$ is a scalar

Comment: That's right, because it's not: covariances among three random variables form a [*matrix*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix).

Comment: $I\sigma$ where $I$ is an identity matrix and $\sigma$ is a standard deviation is not right; it should be $I\sigma^2$ since the diagonal entries in a covariance matrix are _variances_ not standard deviations. More to the point, $I\sigma^2$ is the covariance matrix of three _uncorrelated_ random variables with identical variances $\sigma^2$, and in this case, since you (seem to be) assuming joint normality, the random variables are independent as well. You "... can't see covariance like this..." because  that is **not** the covariance matrix of dependent jointly normal random variables.

Comment: I found this: http://courses.ee.sun.ac.za/Pattern_Recognition_813/lectures/lecture03/node4.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's lots of ways we *can* calculate sigma :) . I think you want the maximum likelihood one though, as that's how you've calculated the mean.

It's going to be a bit easier to look at this in terms of vectors. Let's concatenate our data into a set of vectors $v_1$, $v_2$, etc, up to $v_n$ where

$$
v_1 = [x_1, y_1, z_1]^T
$$

i.e.  we're just taking your three dimensional data and stacking it. Similarly, we have the mean $\mu' = [\mu(1)', \mu(2)', \mu(3)']^T$. In that case the log likelihood $L$ of your data is

$$
L = \sum_{i=1}^n \log \Bigg(\frac{1}{(2\pi\sigma^2)^{3/2}}e^{\frac{|| v_i - \mu' ||^2}{-2\sigma^2}} \Bigg)
$$

If you're not sure why this is, look up multivariate gaussians, set the covariance matrix equal to $\sigma^2 I$ and the number of dimensions to $3$.

**NB - the standard way to define an isotropic covariance matrix is by setting it equal to $\sigma^2 I$, and not $\sigma I$ as you have. Doing that will confuse anyone who reads your work at a later date, as it looks misleadingly like the usual notation.** As such, you're going to have to be careful when you look at the result of this derivation, and make sure you're clear what the term $\sigma$ refers to in it before you start using it. Otherwise you may end up squaring / square rooting / etc incorrectly.

Okay. So, to make it easier to work with I'm going to expand the logarithm term. It's just some algebra, nothing fancy.

$$
L = -\frac{3n}{2}\log(2\pi\sigma^2) - \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{|| v_i - \mu' ||^2}{2\sigma^2}.
$$

Now, to find the maximum likelihood result we differentiate by $\sigma$ and set the whole thing to zero, giving us this,

$$
0 = -\frac{3n}{2}\frac{4\pi\sigma}{2\pi\sigma^2} + \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{|| v_i - \mu' ||^2}{\sigma^3}.
$$

There's a whole bunch of stuff which cancels, and once we isolate the terms in $\sigma$ we're left with

$$
\sigma^2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n|| v_i - \mu' ||^2}{3n}
$$

which you'll notice is equal to

$$
\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{3}\big(\sigma(1)'^2 + \sigma(2)'^2 + \sigma(3)'^2\big)
$$

i.e. the overall variance is equal to the mean variance in each dimension. Which makes a nice, intuitive sense.

That's the maximum likelihood result. However, like I said right at the start, it's not the only thing we can do. For example, this result is slightly biased - not a problem if $n$ is large, but if it's small you may want to investigate these. Also, you could find a bayesian result, which uses priors and will probably be different as a result. But for now I think this ought to give you what you're looking for.

Comment: Wow thanks for the answers. this is what I looking for. I think I have a new question, but I will ask that in a new topic.